# XmlException: a name did not start with a legal character 32 ( ) Line 57, position 66

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am having a couple problems

1. Every time I create a new script (the first one in fact and I haven't done anything yet) it's giving me this error:

> XmlException: a name did not start with a legal character 32 ( ) Line 56, position 66.

I have tried deleting the script and creating a new one but I get the same error.

2. When I click on the script to open it in Visual Studio. Visual Studio says 'Error while trying to load the project' After I click the 'ok' error dialogue boxes the script opens but in the solutions tab in Visual Studio it doesn't show the proper hierarchy of where my project is saved just the project name and the C# assembly script it "couldn't open" in red.

I have tried deleting the whole project and recreating a new one since Visual Studio is having trouble locating the project. But that didn't change anything either.

Has anyone had these same problems and how did you solve them?

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and Unity 2018.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Not quite sure how I fixed it. All I did was delete the whole project and created a new one and changed some folder names that the project was saved in. I must have missed some detail when naming something and it probably was a space somewhere.

Comment: @littlegodplan You can supply this as an answer to your own question, then delete the comment. In a few days, you can accept your own answer. That way, this question ends up as having an accepted answer rather than looking like it is unanswered.

Comment: @littlegodpan1 what did the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by ampersand (&) char in my project folder. I solved it by renaming the folder. Hope it helps too!